# Dynamic JsonProperty using Jackson with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I developped a Spring Boot application. This application can be deployed to a test or prod environment, the application is using REST API for making requests. I use POJOs as wrapper, with the JsonProperty annotations containing the field IDs for the API,  that it is being pushed to.

ie

```
@JsonProperty("field_001)
private String name;

@JsonProperty("field_002)
private String address;
```

The field labels for these values differ on the test endpoint. So the test endpoint might expect the properties to map as

```
@JsonProperty("field_005)
private String name;

@JsonProperty("field_006)
private String address;
```

I would like to be able to utilize the Spring Boot native support for profile based properties files. To read in the JsonProperty annotation values at run time from an external properties file.

So for example,

There might be three files application.properties, application-test.properties and application-prod.properties. Spring Boot could read in the test or prod properties in addition to the vanilla properties file based on the "spring.profiles.active" setting.

...-test.properties would contain the constant values for the test server fields. And ...-prod.properties would contain the constant values for the prod server fields.

Nesting annotations such as Spring's @Value tag, like this:

```
@JsonProperty(@Value("${property.file.reference.here})) 
doesn't seem to work.
```

Best regards

Comment: Why are none of your quotes closed?

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonProperty(@Value("${property.file.reference.here}))` won't work simply because :

`@JsonProperty` uses a String as value, but `@Value` is an '`Annotation`', so that's not a String value, writing it will give you the following error :

> Error:(34, 12) java: annotation not valid for an element of type java.lang.String

Plus, `@Value` will be loaded "once" when spring context loaded.

**Edit**

If you wish to use test/dev and prod properties, better create a properties file under your test resources package, they will be loaded automatically. (i'm using it that way).

There is actually another approach, is to modify the annotation value at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed ELAYADI. I don't understand you idea how I can process with the file under my test resources package. I have two files: application.properties for dev environement and another for prod environement.

Comment: No I'm still searching. Do you have any ideas